# Firebase: using Accept: text/event-stream on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, firebase, event-stream

I'm trying to use the Firebase API on the Windows Phone through the EventSource / Server-Sent Events protocol.

The code below works when I don't set the `Accept: text/event-stream`. In this way I get the entire requested json.
But the task doesn't continue when the *Accept* is set to *text/event-stream*.

With `request.AllowReadStreamBuffering` set to `false` it doesn't change

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.Accept = "text/event-stream";
//request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;

Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,
                                                        request.EndGetResponse,
                                                        null)
            .ContinueWith(async t => 
                { 
                    using (Stream s = t.Result.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
                        int bytesRead = await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                        string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
                    }
                });
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've never used Firebase with SSE. But from this example I get the impression that it send `put` and `patch` verbs, not `get` like what you handle: https://github.com/firebase/EventSource-Examples/blob/master/ruby/chat.rb#L62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.Method = "GET"` refers to the HTTP action method which is different than the PUT action of the SSE protocol. If I set the request method to PUT I get an error.

I don't know why, but I resolved upgrading to Windows Phone 8.1 and using the `HTTPClient` in the `Windows.Web.Http` namespace (it's not available in 8.0).

Here's the code:

```
    Uri url = new Uri("https://test.firebaseio.com/...");
    var request = new HttpClient();
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new Windows.Web.Http.Headers.HttpMediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/event-stream"));

    Task task = request.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask().ContinueWith(t =>
         {
             t.Result.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync().AsTask().ContinueWith(async t1 =>
                {
                    IInputStream istr = await t1;
                    Stream s = istr.AsStreamForRead();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
                    int bytesRead = await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    string content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
                });
        });
```